# Google Login and Facebook Login is not working in google chrome extension made in React Js which which is wrapped with iframe

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, react-google-login

I am trying to implement login through google and Facebook in chrome extension made in React JS which is wrapped with iframe.

The package that i am using for google login is "react-google-login" and for facebook login  i am using "react-facebook-login".

In both cases google login and facebook login button are visible, but in case of google login the button is disable(not clickable) and in case of facebook login the button is clickable but the facebook user selector pop up don't load.

```
 <GoogleLogin
                                disabled={false}
                                clientId="**********-akj6ujapgd722u0kqaib2lmca3mu71vt.apps.googleusercontent.com"
                                buttonText="Login"
                                onSuccess={this.responseGoogle}
                                onFailure={this.responseGoogle}
                                cookiePolicy={'single_host_origin'}
                            />
```

For google login i am seeing this warning message "Uncaught Type Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'load')
at HTMLScriptElement."

Comment: It's very difficult to us to help you without seeing any code

Comment: @razvans Hi, i have updated the description with the code for google login. Can you please look at it